# $wpdb -> insert is not working in custom form action

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, insert

I'm trying to insert data into WordPress database using "wpdb insert", form data getting correctly using POST method but not saving it into database table.

I just started Wordpress and having the basic syntax errors, please help.

I'm using Cpanel, and this is my first experience on a live server.
I have successfully done everything on localhost and local database, but now on WordPress, I'm having troubles.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['booknow'])){

  global $wpdb;
  $tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'bookings';
  $insert = $wpdb->insert( $tablename, 
  array(

    'customer_name' => $_POST['name'],
    'customer_email'=> $_POST['email'],
    'customer_phone'=> $_POST['phone'],
    'pickup_location'=> $_POST['pickup'],
    'dropoff_location'=> $_POST['dropoff'],
    'pickup_date'=> $_POST['date']
   ),

  array(
    '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'
  ) 

  );
}
?>
```

I want to save these entries into table 'bookings'

Answer (score 0):

you can use like, $wpdb->insert()

```
$wpdb->insert('table_name', array(
    'column 1' => 'value 1',
    'column 2' => 'value 2',
    'column 3' => 'value 3'
));
```